# How to map the keys of two arrays of the same length with each other?

Tags: javascript

I want to map the key of one array to another nested array. Both arrays have the same length.

**Before:**

```
const idListToInsert = [{ idToInsert: 1 }, { idToInsert: 3 }, { idToInsert: 4 }];

const otherObjectList = [
  [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
  [{ id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }],
  [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }],
];
```

**Target:**

```
const targetList = [
  [
    { id: 1, idToInsert: 1 },
    { id: 2, idToInsert: 1 },
    { id: 3, idToInsert: 1 },
    { id: 4, idToInsert: 1 },
  ],
  [
    { id: 5, idToInsert: 3 },
    { id: 6, idToInsert: 3 },
    { id: 7, idToInsert: 3 },
  ],
  [
    { id: 8, idToInsert: 4 },
    { id: 9, idToInsert: 4 },
  ],
];
```

I'm having a bit of a hard time finding the starting point for this problem, especially because of the nested structure of the second array.

I am thankful for each hint.

Comment: Start iterating otherObjectList and use Its inner array index to get an appropriate object from idListToInsert and merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is most clear code I could come up with..

```js
const idListToInsert = [{ idToInsert: 1 }, { idToInsert: 3 }, { idToInsert: 4 }];

const otherObjectList = [
  [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
  [{ id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }],
  [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }],
];

const result = otherObjectList.map((item, index) => item.map((value) => ({
    ...value,
    ...idListToInsert[index],
})));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the outer array `otherObjectList` and their inner arrays and create a new object with additional properties.

```js
const
    idListToInsert = [{ idToInsert: 1 }, { idToInsert: 3 }, { idToInsert: 4 }],
    otherObjectList = [[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }], [{ id: 5 }, { id: 6 }, { id: 7 }], [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }]],
    result = otherObjectList.map((a, i) => a.map(o => ({ ...o, ...idListToInsert[i] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const targetList = []
otherObjectList.forEach((subarray, index) => {
   const temp = []
   subarray.forEach(id => {
      temp.push({id,  idListToInsert[index]})
   })
   targetList.push(temp)
})
```

It is untested but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helping you

```
var targetList = otherObjectList.map((ele,index)=>ele.map(obj=>({...obj, ...idListToInsert[index]})))
console.log(targetList)
```